# Accessing SQL Server 2008 R2 from a service in Delphi XE8

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, sql-server-2008, delphi, tms

I'm writing a client and TWO servers in Delphi XE8.
One server is a normal program with forms, the second is a windows service.
Both expose the same three functions: a simple "ping", a file transfer, and a query on a MS SQL 2008 R2 database.

When I use client and the "program" server, all works well, I can write a query on the client, send the query to the server, and receive data.

When I use client and the "service" server, some parts work, but if I can write a query on the client, send the query to the server, the server receives the query, but it can't access the database.

I work on a VMWare virtual machine Win7 32 bit, with Delphi XE8 and TMS Sparkle as transport system, and DBExpress ad DB access.
I have turned off antivirus and firewall.
SQL Server is well configured, protocols, ports, browser is running.
The service runs under LOCAL SYSTEM (with every other user the service can't start, I don't understand why).

I think TMS creates a thread every time it receives a request, and my code is inside this thread.
Inside the thread I create a form, a TSQLConnection with owner the form, and a TSQLQuery, and try to open the connection.

In my log I find "SQL Error Code: 53": server not found or ... (there is nothing after "or").

I suppose it could be a permission problem, but i don't know for sure.

Some ideas?

Comment: "Inside the thread I create a form"  Inside a service?  Btw does your service attempt to access any resource using a UNC pathname?

Comment: Try to define a user and password with administrator privileges on "services.msc". Additionally, since service application is impossible to debug, you can implement a routine to save file logs in some critical events. This helps you to get the errors content more precisely.

Comment: @R.PSilveira Delphi service applications can be debugged using the  `Attach to process` item in the Run menu. The IDE needs to be running with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I made a mistake in the SQL password ...